# You need to authorize access before proceeding

Tags: php, video, upload, access-token, google-api-php-client

i'm trying to upload video on you tube using my application. i'm using google-api-php-client for uploading video

```
    <?php

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
set_include_path("google-api-php-client/src/");

require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * {{ Google Cloud Console }} <{{ https://cloud.google.com/console }}>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {

  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
  $sessionToken = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);

}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try{

    $video_id = $_SESSION['video_id']; 

    require_once '../include/DbHandler.php';
    $db = new DbHandler();
    $result = $db->get_video_details($video_id);

    $video_tags = $result["tags"];//"test_video_for_vidreporter";
    $video_desc = $result["comments"];//"DESC";
    $video_url = $result["video_url"];
    $video = substr($video_url, strrpos($video_url, '/') + 1);

    $tag_array = Array();
    $myArray = explode(',', $video_tags);
    for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($myArray); $i++){
        $tag = $myArray[$i];
        array_push($tag_array,$tag);
    }
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = "../include/uploads/".$video;

    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle($video_tags);
    $snippet->setDescription($video_desc);
    $snippet->setTags($tag_array);

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);


    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $status['snippet']['title'],
        $status['id']);

    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';

  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to upload video on my you tube channel. once mobile user upload video using application. first video upload on my server then it upload on Facebook page then on you tube channel. but i need to click on **authorize access** then it move to you tube and then i need to select my you tube channel. but i want to  directly upload video on you tube channel. please help me out

thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have found a solution for it after a long research. we need to make a file key.txt and save the access token we get in response in JSON format. then we need to use the same access token for the next request. so that it will found accesstoken in file and wont ask again for **authorize access**

Comment: Can you please share with us how you made that ?

Comment: follow this tutorial.. https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide. 
your reputation says that you can easily understand this tutorial. :)